# How could I stream Audio in iphone after a certain buffering amount occured?

Tags: iphone, buffering, avplayer, audiostreamer

I am using Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer class for my audio streaming app. I need to make the audio stream without any interruption. Can anyone help me in this? I think there is something to do with the buffering size. As am new to iphone developing please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well no, you can't force the audio to play uninterrupted, you can increase the buffer size. 
Increasing the buffer will help a bit, don't make it to big or it will take a long time to buffer.

But the most important thing is the mobile internet, which isn't the best to stream Audio.
If the connection is dropped then your stream will be interrupted and there is nothing you can really do about it.

Comment: Thank you rckoenes. I too think increasing the buffer size will help. I was searching for any other methods that could help me in uninterrupted audio streaming. Well, Thanks again..